# Normalizing html lost space inside between two tags

Tags: php, regex

i use this function for normalize html:

```
function normalize_html( $html ) {
    return preg_replace(
        array(
            "/\>[^\S]+/s", "/[^\S]+\</s", "/(\s)+/s", "/\<[^\s\S]+?\>/",
        ),
        array(
            ">", "<", "\\1", "",
        ), $html );
}
```

When i have something like:

```
<p>text: <b>bold</b></p>
```

It return: `text:bold` losting `space` between `text:` and `bold`.
How i can fix this problem into function for not lost this space?

Thanks.

Comment: The second pattern `"/[^\S]+\</s"` is the same as `\s+"/</s"` which matches 1+ whitespace chars before the `<`. You can update that to `"/</s"` See https://3v4l.org/jBElF

Comment: Ok  thanks work for space to left of tag but doing it lost space after tag when begin text. For example having </b> text it return </b>text. How i can fix too it? Thank again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex and html is usually not a good mix, but as this is about the whitespaces and brackets you might give this a go.

The second pattern `"/[^\S]+\</s"` is the same as `\s+"/</s"` which matches 1+ whitespace chars before the `<`. You can update that to `"/</s"`

**Note** that this pattern `[^\s\S]` will not match anything, as it means do not match any char due to the negation using `[^`, so you can omit the last part.

You don't have to escape the `<` and the `>` and you can omit `/s` after the pattern as it makes the dot to match a newline but there is no dot in the pattern.

```
function normalize_html( $html ) {
    return preg_replace(
        array(
            "/>\s+/", "/</", "/(\s)+/"
        ),
        array(
            ">", "<", "\\1", "",
        ), $html );
}

echo normalize_html("<p>text: <b>bold</b></p>");
```

Output

```
<p>text: <b>bold</b></p>
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/9LP7g)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take out HTML tags, you can just use `strip_tags`:

```
echo strip_tags('<p>text: <b>bold</b></p>'); // OUTPUT: "text: bold"
```

Comment: No, i just done a example for not lost space when get situation as in example. In general it is appllied to full html web page where i delete all spaces, new lines, etc. The function work fine but when get a space inside two tag clear too it. I want just which this space is saved and not losted. How i can to do it?